# How to get list of all input IDs within a certain form in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I'm facing following issue - let's see I have following HTML:

```
<form action="/test/" class="" id="testForm" method="post">
  <input class="full-width valid" id="Description" name="Description" type="text" value="test" />
  <input class="full-width valid" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="test" />
  <input class="full-width valid" id="Surname" name="Surname" type="text" value="test" />
  ...
</form>
```

Now I want to check all form input fields if they are disabled. Is there any way how can I do that dynamically in Robot Framework? I want to avoid enumerating all IDs.

Not sure if it's good idea to use Execute Javascript keyword?

Answer (score 4):

You can try iterating through all the input elements as follows

```
*** Test Case ***
Check Input Fields If Disabled
  ${count}=   Get Matching Xpath Count  //form[@id='testForm']/input
  : FOR  ${i}  IN  RANGE  1  {count}+1
  \  Element Should Be Disabled  //form[@id='testForm']/input[${i}]
```